# Drupal Filefield Source install

Tags: drupal, drupal-files

Filefield Source is a module which works with CCK and Filefield which allows users to select files from already uploaded files, instead of having them upload a file multiple times.

I installed the module, but cannot see it.  I am using CCK version 2.8 and Filefield version 3.7.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  Probably just some stupid mistake on my part.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your content type and add a new field with type **file**. So, go to Administer -> Content Management -> *Your content type* -> Manage fields.

Comment: Ah... When I go to Manage Fields -> Configure, there is a "File Sources" link, which I think is new.

Comment: This is not all ( see here: http://drupal.org/node/1873808 ) You also need to go to _edit_ for the file or image field and enable the specific options.